# Running simplescheme in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to run code for 'simplescheme' (http://bryanchadwick.com/simplescheme/) on DrRacket to test it before putting it on the device's android. I could not find "#lang simplescheme" in the list of languages provided in DrRacket's menu.

I have 'simplescheme's android app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=chadwick.apps.simplescheme) installed on the device, but how can I test the code first on a desktop? I could not find 'simplescheme' interpreter for Linux or Windows on the net.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your comments/answers.

Answer (score 3):

According the Simple Scheme web-site: http://bryanchadwick.com/simplescheme/index.html

Simple Scheme is a language inspired by Scheme and Racket.

This means that the only implementation of Simple Scheme is the Android one.

There are however two options to run your programs on the desktop.

The first one is to install an Android Emulator and run Simple Scheme in the emulator. This will allow you to run the real Simple Scheme.

The other options is to use `#lang racket` and restrict your self to use the constructs that are supported by Simple Scheme: http://bryanchadwick.com/simplescheme/index.html#functionlist

On the plus side this allows you to use DrRacket, but you risk using a construct missing from Simple Scheme.

Comment: So only these functions are available. It seems that neither user input nor file read functions are available at present in this otherwise excellent app.

Comment: If you use big-bang you can react to `on-mouse` and `on-react`. I can't see file functions either. Consider sending Bryan an email.

Answer (score 1):

***NB!*** This answer is off topic as it's about Simply Scheme and not SimpleScheme. I'll leave it here as the names are rather similar

Racketeer and SO-er [Danny Yoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723947/dyoo) has made a Racket module language to support Simply Scheme in the racket language suite. In Racket with the bottom left dropdown set to "Determine language from source" and replace the definitions window, including the `#lang` line  to the following:

```
#lang planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2

(se (butlast (bf "this"))
    "world")
```

And press <kbd>RUN</kbd>. It will download and install the language and then you'll see the answer `(hi "world")`. The first time around you might see an error, but my experience is that it will go away on a consecutive run.

The definitions will have all the simply scheme features described in the [the documentation](http://www.hashcollision.org/simply-scheme/index.html). Happy hacking!

Comment: simple-scheme (http://bryanchadwick.com/simplescheme/index.html) is for android but simply-scheme does not appear to be so. I want to try Scheme/Racket on Android.

Comment: @mso I might have been too quick and mixed the two.. I'll delete this answer as it's off topic...

Comment: @mso Racket is [ported to Android](http://www.wedesoft.de/racket-on-android.html). From the article it seems it runs native.

Comment: I think you should let your answer be there since the names are so similar.

Comment: @mso I'll leave it as is then. Also know that Danny also made [Whalesong](http://www.hashcollision.org/whalesong/) that converts a subset of racket to JavaScript.. I imagine that might work in an android app as well.